# C# Multiple If statement replacement

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a practice program that calculates a persons overall grade.  The test consists of three parts each with different weightings.  Part 1 is worth 5 grades, part two 3 grades and part 3 is worth 2 grades.

So if a person got A B C they would receive 5A 3B and 2C.

Now, in order to receive and A/B/C overall requires a certain amount of each grade.  For example in order to receive an A overall you need to have at least 5A's and 7  of the grades must be B or higher and all the grades need to be C or or higher.

B, C, D etc all have their own requirements too.

What is the best way to code this as at the moment I am using a counter for each grade and then doing if/else if statements to check the amount of each grade a person has got like so:

```
 if (aGradeCount >= 5)
    {
                //Add total grade
            }
        }
    }

    //To receive a B
    if(bGradeCount >= 3 && aGradeCount <5 && cGradeCount >=2) 
    {
        if(bGradeCount + cGradeCount +dGradeCount + aGradeCount>= 7)
        {
            if(dGradeCount <= 3)
            {

                //Add new total grade
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I understand this is terrible practice, but how can I code this better?  Using a switch statement?  If so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: There is something messed up in your code above; there are way too many close curly braces in the first if statement. Can you show how the code is actually structured?

Comment: `if(bGradeCount >= 3 && aGradeCount < 5 && cGradeCount >= 2 && dGradeCount <= 3 && aGradeCount + bGradeCount + cGradeCount + dGradeCount  >= 7){...}` you can move the `dGradeCount <= 3` to the end of the `if()` if you need to worry about short circuiting.

Comment: The nested ifs are ok, though the grading policy itself is bizarre. I don't think I ever encountered such a grading scheme - is it a real world one, or something from the Story Problem alternate universe?

Answer (score 13):

> how can I code this better?

Write a specification. Then for every concept mentioned in the specification, write a method. Here's part of a specification; you already wrote it:

> in order to receive an A overall you need to have at least 5 A's and least 7 of the grades must be B or higher and all the grades need to be C or better.

Break it down

```
in order to receive an A overall
    at least 5 A's AND 
    at least 7 of the grades must be B or higher AND
    all the grades need to be C or better
```

OK, now we can start turning that into a method:

```
static bool QualifiesForA(int aCount, int bCount, int cCount, int dCount)
{
    // In order to receive an A overall we require:    

    // TODO: at least 5 A's AND 
    // TODO: at least 7 of the grades must be B or higher AND
    // TODO: all the grades need to be C or better

    // If these conditions are not met then an A is not earned.
    return false;
}
```

All right we have turned our specification into code. Wrong code, but code. Let's keep going. We have a line of a specification. Write a method:

```
static bool AtLeastFiveA(int aCount) 
{
  return aCount >= 5;
}
```

Hey, that was a correct method. We are making progress. Now use it:

```
static bool QualifiesForA(int aCount, int bCount, int cCount, int dCount)
{
    // In order to receive an A overall we require:    
    // at least 5 A's AND 
    // TODO: at least 7 of the grades must be B or higher AND
    // TODO: all the grades need to be C or better

    bool atLeast5A = AtLeastFiveA(aCount);

    // If these conditions are not met then an A is not earned.
    return false;
}
```

Now we have another problem. At least 7 are B or higher.  OK, write a method:

```
static bool AtLeastSevenB(int aCount, int bCount)
{
  return aCount + bCount >= 7;
}
```

Another correct method! Use it!

```
static bool QualifiesForA(int aCount, int bCount, int cCount, int dCount)
{
    // In order to receive an A overall we require:    
    // at least 5 A's AND 
    // at least 7 of the grades must be B or higher AND
    // TODO: all the grades need to be C or better

    bool atLeast5A = AtLeastFiveA(aCount);
    bool atLeast7B = AtLeastSevenB(aCount, bCount);
    // If these conditions are not met then an A is not earned.
    return false;
}
```

Now we need the last bit:

```
static bool NoD(int dCount)
{
  return dCount == 0;
}
```

Put it together.

```
static bool QualifiesForA(int aCount, int bCount, int cCount, int dCount)
{
    // In order to receive an A overall we require:    
    // at least 5 A's AND 
    // at least 7 of the grades must be B or higher AND
    // all the grades need to be C or better

    bool atLeast5A = AtLeastFiveA(aCount);
    bool atLeast7B = AtLeastSevenB(aCount, bCount);
    bool noD = NoD(dCount);
    if (atLeast5A && atLeast7B && noD) 
      return true;

    // If these conditions are not met then an A is not earned.
    return false;
}
```

Now, the question to ask yourself is:

- Is this code correct?  GET IT CORRECT FIRST. This code is very verbose but I'll tell you right now, it *exactly* matches the specification you gave.
- Once the code is correct, can we make it more clear?

Yes; we could for instance say:

```
static bool QualifiesForA(int aCount, int bCount, int cCount, int dCount)
{
    // In order to receive an A overall we require:    
    // at least 5 A's AND 
    // at least 7 of the grades must be B or higher AND
    // all the grades need to be C or better

    bool atLeast5A = AtLeastFiveA(aCount);
    bool atLeast7B = AtLeastSevenB(aCount, bCount);
    bool noD = NoD(dCount);
    return atLeast5A && atLeast7B && noD;
}
```

And now maybe you will say, you know, some of these methods are unnecessary abstractions, maybe I can just replace them with their bodies:

```
static bool QualifiesForA(int aCount, int bCount, int cCount, int dCount)
{
    // In order to receive an A overall we require:    
    // at least 5 A's AND 
    // at least 7 of the grades must be B or higher AND
    // all the grades need to be C or better

    bool atLeast5A = aCount >= 5;
    bool atLeast7B = aCount + bCount >= 7;
    bool noD = dCount == 0;
    return atLeast5A && atLeast7B && noD;
}
```

The point is: we start from a very verbose, **CLEARLY CORRECT** program, and then we make small, simple, clearly correct transformations to make it more concise. When you think you have a good balance of concision and readability, stop.

OK, now you have solved the problem of "did we earn an A?" Now you do "did we earn a B?"  and so on.  Write a specification for every part, and then write code that *clearly implements the specification*.

This sounds like a heavyweight process, but this will pay huge dividends as you learn how to program. Your code will be better organized, it will be less buggy, it will be easier to read and understand and modify.

The point of this technique is to focus on *obvious correctness of every part*.  Always concentrate on *obvious correctness*. A program which is correct but you cannot tell it is correct is a program that might not be correct! Always concentrate on correctness *first*. Making a wrong program more elegant, or faster, or more feature complete means that you have an elegant, fast, rich-featured bug farm.

Summing up:

- Write clear specifications.
- Write code to clearly match the spec.
- Tiny methods are A-OK.  You can always eliminate them later.
- Correctness is more important than everything else; make the code better once you know it is correct.

Comment: In addition, I would also get rid of the 'magic' numbers, and either make them constants or use an enumeration which will help out a lot in the readability aspect of the checks.

Comment: @d.moncada: Sure. We could go a lot farther than that. This is plainly a beginner programmer here so let's not get into the pattern of constructing a hierarchy of policy objects and then applying policy to data, blah blah blah. The point I wanted to get across here is that you organize your code better by having *organized ideas* in the first place.

Comment: Thank you for laying that out, it makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @KerrFloyyd: You're welcome. This is how I learned to program. This is how I still program! As you get better you start doing more and more of these steps in your head rather than on the screen. Doing them on the screen builds up the mental patterns of thought so that you can do them fast in your head later.

Comment: @EricLippert: great guidance. I'd use a bit of Single Responsibility Principle to make the code even more understandable & help with breaking the problem down a bit more.

Comment: This answer is pure gold, I wished I could have learned this with an answer like this back when I started programming, instead of learning it the hard way, by trial and error... MANY errors! :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if that's terrible practice. It's a little unnecessary, since there's nothing else in the block, but another if statement. You can use more && operators and parenthesis if you just want to use one if statement.

```
if ((bGradeCount >= 3 && aGradeCount <5 && cGradeCount >=2)  &&
    (bGradeCount + cGradeCount +dGradeCount + aGradeCount>= 7) &&
    (dGradeCount <= 3))
{
    char b = 'B';
    person.TotalGrade = b.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Parenthesis make it more readable, but I don't think they are necessary since everything is `&&`ed.

Comment: No they're not necessary at all. Just a way to keep his comparisons separate and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

For code clarity I would do this that way :

```
//Main function
{
///code
     if(MethodWhichDescribesLogic(aGradeCOunt,bGradeCount,cGradeCount,dGradeCount){
          char b = 'B';
          person.TotalGrade = b.ToString();
     }
}
```

Then in some place else :

```
 bool MethodWhichDescribesLogic(type aGradeCount, type  bGradeCount, type cGradeCount, type dGradeCount){
    return 
       (PassingGrade(bGradeCount,aGradeCount,cGradeCount) &&
       GoodGradesType(bGradeCount,cGradeCount,dGradeCount,aGradeCount) &&
       dGradeCount <= 3);
    }


  bool PassingGradesCount(type bGradeCount,type aGradeCount,type cGradeCount)
  {
      return bGradeCount >= 3 && aGradeCount <5 && cGradeCount >=2;
  }


  bool GoodGradesCount(type cGradeCount,type bGradeCount,type aGradeCount,type dGradeCount)
  {
      return bGradeCount + cGradeCount +dGradeCount + aGradeCount>= 7;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remember that every if-else switches can be replaced by conditional table.
So if overall grades count would be like 10. It could be

```
A   B   C   Overall

5   7   10  A

4   7   10  B
```

Then you make array of it and find where you are in the array.

For example (I admit that I'm puzzled by your example so I might get it wrong here.):

```
var grades = new[]{
  new { A = 5. B = 7, C = 10, Overall = "A"},
  new { A = 4, B = 7, C = 10, Overall = "B"},
  ...
}

var myGrade = grades.FirstOrDefault(g => myA >= g.A && myB >= g.B && enoughC)
```

With proper formatting it looks much better than tons of if's. And you always have your choice table in front of you.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, make use of Boolean Algebra in the `OverallGrade()` to see which cases you **don't need to consider**. For example, if for checking an A grade you have already seen that `gradeDistribution.A >= 5`, don't test `gradeDistribution.A < 5` when testing for grade 'B' as it is obvious that if you are testing the case for B, you have already tested `gradeDistribution.A < 5` as true.

---

Next, put the grade calculation in another method and make that method return as early as possible.

---

Finally, in order to get the overall grade, you may write the method as:

```
private static char OverallGrade(int partA, int partB, int partC)
{
    //Now in this method, check one by one which 
    //overall grade the provided values fall in

    //Call another method to get count of individual As, Bs, Cs etc
    var gradeDistribution = GetIndividualCount(partA, partB, partC);

    //Now, first check for A and return immediately if true
    if (gradeDistribution.A >= 5) return 'A';

    //Now, check for B and again return if the values satisfy for B
    if (gradeDistribution.B >=3 
        && gradeDistribution.C <= 2
        && gradeDistribution.D <= 3
        && ...)
        return 'B';

    //Keep adding for each case and return as soon as you find the grade.
}
```

Now, the class `GradeDistribution`, whose variable we have used above can be created which will hold count of each grade:

```
public class GradeDistribution
{
    public int A; //Count for Grade A
    public int B; //Count for Grade B
    public int C; //Count for Grade C
    public int D; //Count for Grade D
}
```

The above code is an example of introducing a class for an entity that does not exist in real world.

Next, `GetIndividualCount()` can be written as:

```
private static GradeDistribution GetIndividualCount(int partA, int partB, int partC)
{
    var gradeDistribution = new GradeDistribution();
    /*

    Calculate and assign values to gradeDistribution.A, gradeDistribution.B...

    */
    return gradeDistribution;
}
```